# How to disable or uncheck a checkbox in ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, ng-grid

I need disable or uncheck a checkbox depending on a condition. I try this solution [how to disallow selection with beforeSelectionChange for select All chekbox selection in ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610945/how-to-disallow-selection-with-beforeselectionchange-for-select-all-chekbox-sele/30609453#30609453), but the row (the data) it's selected.

```
$scope.gridQueryReporte = {

data: 'dataPaginadaIntegrantes',
columnDefs: [{
    field: 'numeroSolicitud',
    displayName: 'label_id_solicitud',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'tipoNumIdSolicitud',
    displayName: 'Tipo y No. Id Solicitud',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'nombreSolicitud',
    displayName: 'Nombre Solicitud',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'tipoNumIdIntegrante',
    displayName: 'Tipo y No. Id Integrante',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'nombreIntegrante',
    displayName: 'label_nombre_integrante',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'fechaPublicacion',
    displayName: 'label_fecha_publicacion_solicitud',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'estado',
    displayName: 'label_estado',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'anotacion',
    displayName: 'label_con_anotacion',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid()
}, {
    field: 'idIntegrante',
    displayName: 'label_titulo_detalle_solicitud',
    headerCellTemplate: loadHeaderGrid(),
    cellTemplate: loadCellGrid({
        type: 'img',
        image: 'verDetalleGrid',
        toValidate: 'idIntegrante',
        funcion: 'abrirModalDetalle(row.entity)'
    })
}],
primaryKey: "idIntegrante",
enableRowSelection: true,
showSelectionCheckbox: true,
multiSelect: true,
selectWithCheckboxOnly: true,
selectedItems: $scope.integranteSeleccionado,
showColumnMenu: true,
enablePaging: true,
showFooter: true,
pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptionsIntegrantes,
filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
showFilter: true,

afterSelectionChange: function (rowItem) {
    $scope.contadorBanderaBoton = $scope.gridQueryReporte.selectedItems.length;

    $scope.selectedIDs = [];
    var objetoIntegrante = {};

    angular.forEach($scope.integranteSeleccionado, function (item) {
        //here i want uncheck or disable the checkbox                     
        if (item.rutaReporteRiesgos == null || item.rutaReporteRiesgos == "") {
            if (rowItem.selected) {
                $scope.gridQueryReporte.selectRow(rowItem.rowIndex, false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

};

Comment: Could we see some code so we know the context of your question a little better?

Comment: hi, with that code i can disable the data selection, but when i do a second search filling the grid,  launchs "TypeError: $scope.gridQueryReporte.selectRow is not a function"

Comment: Currently you don't have a selectRow function defined anywhere and selectRow isn't a method you can just call on your scope. Do you have a function built out for selectRow?

Comment: hi gjanden, No, i haven't.  selectRow is a function for the ng-grid,  http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/. This works fine the first time, the second time launch the exception. I must refresh the page and works again. In other examples i don't see  that this function is defined in the grid options.  It's necessary?

Comment: For example: http://plnkr.co/edit/XES0IP?p=preview .   selectRow isn't defined

Comment: Ok Yeah I see that now. One thing that I am noticing is that the parameters being passed in are either `...selectedRow(index, false)` or in the case of the other stackoverflow it looks like `...selectedRow(rowItem[i].rowIndex, false)`. I wonder if it is somehow is affecting the index. Have you tried throwing in the `[i]`? I think it is getting hung up somehow on the `rowItem.rowIndex`.

Comment: hi, i try this with a for like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610945/how-to-disallow-selection-with-beforeselectionchange-for-select-all-chekbox-sele/30609453#30609453

but its similary, i see on debug and the index its ok

Comment: i add this  "selectRow : function (rowIndex){}," in the  grid options, and now i don't get the error "TypeError: $scope.gridQueryReporte.selectRow is not a function". However  for a second search (and filling the grid), the data its selected despite the row pass the validation

Comment: I solve this. I change the data adding an extra boolean field, and the property "checkboxCellTemplate" and the disable attribute with the value of the boolean field.Thanks